# Can a rotation matrix be written as the convex combination of two rotation matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, rotations

I want to say that for all $R,S \in SO(3)$ and $0 < t < 1$ (note the strict inequalities) with $R \not = S$, we must have $tR + (1-t)S \not \in SO(3)$. I've been trying to think up a counterexample to this but can't imagine any. Is this true? I know that if some $t$ does satisfy this, then we must have $(1-t^2-(1-t)^2)I=t(1-t)(R^TS + S^TR)$, but can't seem to go beyond this. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the determinant. If it's not a unit, then it's not in SO(3). So is there an special case with a 0 determinant for example?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it should suffice to take some unit vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $Rx \ne Sx$, and then observe that $\lVert (tR + (1-t)S) x \rVert < 1$.  Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The determinant of a sum of matrices has no closed-form expression I believe.

Comment: Like @DogeChan said. Perhaps it's the same idea that "the line segment joining two distinct points on the sphere does not intersect the sphere again"?

Comment: Well you don't need a closed form expression. Just an example of two matrices R,S such that tR + (t-1)S = 0 or something else along those lines.

Comment: @DogeChan How would that help in proving (or disproving) my claim?

Comment: -R is in SO(3) if R is in SO(3). So let S=-R and t=1/2.

Comment: @DogeChan I think the OP wants a general statement and not just one example

Comment: @DogeChan You provided a pair of rotation matrices whose convex combination isn't a rotation matrix. I'm well aware such such pairs exist. My question asks if there exists a pair whose sum is rotation matrix.

Comment: If you can find a pair R,S such that $R^TS + S^T R=0$, then there is such a pair. That is, if $R^TS$ is skew-symmetric. For example if the product is in the subgroup of $1$ dimensional rotations.

Comment: How did you conclude that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more succinct variation on previous answers: since each column (and row) of a "rotation matrix" (more generally any orthogonal matrix) is a vector on the unit sphere, any nontrivial convex combination of two rotation matrices induces the same convex relation on their first columns. But all points on the unit sphere are extreme points: it is impossible that a nontrivial convex relation can be satisfied by three distinct points on the unit sphere. Thus the convex combination must be trivial; i.e., all three rotation matrices must agree in their first column. Ditto for all other such columns.Since all columns agree, the matrices agree.

Comment: Yes, it is very succinct explanation. I was considering in my answer chords in the unit circle, but simpler is to use the whole unit sphere, I'm curious, have you been inspired a little by my answer?

Comment: @Widawensen Yes, I just tried to condense your answer.

Comment: Simple and proves the statement! I love it.

Comment: @MathWonkc O.K. You have made it very condensed. Congratulations :)

Answer (score 1):

From Jyrki's answer:
[Additive rotation matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841410/additive-rotation-matrices?noredirect=1&lq=1)

"Assume contrariwise that for certain rotations $R_1,R_2,R_3$ the equation"
$$
tR_1\vec{x}+(1-t)R_2\vec{x}=R_3\vec{x}$$ (*the formula changed by me wrt Jyrki's answer to meet conditions of the problem)

"holds for all $\vec{x}\in\Bbb{R}^3$. If this works for the triple $(R_1,R_2,R_3)$ then multiplying $(*)$ from the left by $R_3^{-1}$ we see that it also works for the triple $(R_3^{-1}R_1,R_3^{-1}R_2,I_3)$. So without loss of generality we can assume that $R_3$ is the identity mapping."

Below my continuation:

therefore for some rotation matrices
$Q_1=R_3^{-1}R_1$, $Q_2=R_3^{-1}R_2$

$tQ_1\vec{x}+(1-t)Q_2\vec{x}=I\vec{x}$

$tQ_1\vec{x} =(t-1)Q_2\vec{x}+ I\vec{x}$

Assume now  $\vec{u}$ is the axis vector of $Q_2$ i.e. $Q_2\vec{u}=\vec{u}$

Then
$tQ_1\vec{u} =(t-1)Q_2\vec{u}+ I\vec{u}=t\vec{u}$

From this

$Q_1\vec{u}=\vec{u}$ so $Q_1$ has the same axis as $Q_2$.

So from initial assumption we have that there are two rotation matrices $Q_1,Q_2$ about **the same axis** that

$tQ_1 +(1-t)Q_2 =I$

But taking now any unit vector $\vec{v}$ lying in the plane of rotation, vector which being rotated with all possible angles defines on this plane an unit circle, we have that point defined by vector

$tQ_1\vec{v} +(1-t)Q_2\vec{v}$ should lie on the **internal** part of the segment with endpoints $Q_1\vec{v}$ and $Q_2\vec{v}$ (these endpoints are lying on the unit circle), and consequently this point doesn't lie on the the unit circle as point $I\vec{v}$ does,

which leads to
**contradiction**.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C = (1 - t) A + t B$ where $A$ and $B$ are the two given rotation matrices, such that

$ A = [a_1, a_2, a_3]$ , $B = [b_1, b_2, b_3] $, and $C = [c_1, c_2, c_3] $

Then, it follows that

$c_1 = (1 - t) a_1 + t b_1$

We want $c_1$ to be a unit vector, so

$1 = (1 - t)^2 (a_1^T a_1) + t^2 (b_1^T b_1) + 2 t (1 - t) (a_1^T b_1 )$

Since $a_1 $ and $b_1$ and unit vectors then

$ 1  = (1 - t)^2 + t^2 + 2 t (1 - t) (a_1^T b_1)$

$ 0 = - 2 t + 2 t^2 + 2 t (1 - t) (a_1^T b_1 ) $

Since $t \ne 0$, then

$ 0 = -2 + 2 t + 2 (1 - t) (a_1^T b_1) $

Thus

$ 0 = -2 (1 - t) + 2 (1 - t) (a_1^T b_1) $

Since $ t \ne 1$ then

$ a_1^T b_1 = 1 $

which means the angle between $a_1$ and $b_1$ is zero.  Similarly,

$a_2^T b_2 = 1 $ and $ a_3^T b_3 = 1 $

And this means, that for $C$ to be a rotation matrix, matrices $A$ and $B$ must be identical.