# Convex combination of unitary matrices equal to another unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

Suppose we have a finite set of positive reals $c_i$ such that $\sum_i c_i = 1$. Define the corresponding unit sum of a set of matrices $M_i$ to be $\sum_i c_i\cdot M_i$.

Does there exist a set of $c_i$ and a set of (more than one!) distinct unitary $M_i$ such that the unit sum is also unitary? If so, what's the smallest matrix dimension for which such a set exists?

Comment: There are sets of distinct unitaries for which $\sum_{i} \sqrt{c_i} M_i$ is also unitary, given any such positive $c_i$. My suspicion is that the answer to your question, however, is "no".

Comment: @BenGrossmann That's close enough to be interesting at least! Do you have a citation?

Comment: I don't have a citation. As an example, however, consider any $c_1,c_2\geq 0$ and $c_1 + c_2 = 1$. The matrix
$$
\sqrt{c_1} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + \sqrt{c_2}\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$
is unitary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma.** *Separating any unitary matrix as $U= A+iB$ where $A$ and $B$ are real,  one sees that each column  $A_j$   has length at most one*.

Proof. Since $I=U^*U = (A^t-i B^t)( A+i B) = A^t A + B^t B + i(A^tB- B^tA) \iff A^tA+ B^tB=I$ and $ A^tB=B^tA$. Thus from the $(j,j)$ entry of the identity $A^tA+B^tB=I$  we see that the $j_{th}$ columns of $A$ and $B$ are related by $||A_j||^2+ ||B_j||^2=1$.

Suppose now that a nontrivial convex combination of unitary matrices is unitary: $U=\sum_k c_k U_k$. After multiplying across by $U^{-1}$ deduce that $$I= \sum_k c_k \tilde U_k$$ for some new set of unitary matrices $\tilde U_k$.

Extract the real part of this relation to obtain $I= \sum_k c_k\tilde A_k$.

Each column of this latter identity asserts that each column of $I$, which is a vector on the unit sphere, is expressed as a convex combination of vectors that each have length at most one. Since the sphere is strictly convex, there can be no such nontrivial convex combination.

This is a simple modification of a previous argument in a related post: [Can a rotation matrix be written as the convex combination of two rotation matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4631314/can-a-rotation-matrix-be-written-as-the-convex-combination-of-two-rotation-matri/4632356#4632356)