# Can a convex combination of matrices in the unit spectral norm ball be unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices, spectral-norm

This is a generalization of ["Unit sum" of unitary matrices equal to another unitary matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4671327).

Does there exist a finite set of at least two distinct matrices $M_i$ with spectral norm $\leq 1$ and positive reals $c_i$ such that $$\sum_i c_i = 1 \land \sum_i c_i \cdot M_i = U$$ where $U$ is a unitary matrix? If so, what's the smallest matrix dimension for which such a set exists?

Comment: What do you mean by the spectral norm ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc The maximum singular value - the square root of the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $A^*A $, where $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$

Comment: That's exactly the operator norm of $A.$ In that case the answer is negative,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is negative. Assume $\|M_i\|\le 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^nc_iM_i=U,$ $c_i>0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i=1.$ Then
for $0\neq v\in \mathbb{C}^n$ we have
$$\|v\|=\|Uv\|\le \sum_{i=1}^nc_i\|M_iv\|\le \sum_{i=1}^nc_i\|v\|=\|v\|$$ Therefore $\|M_iv\|=\|v\|$ for any $i$ and the equality occurs in the triangle inequality
$$\left \|\sum_{i=1}^n c_iM_iv\right \|=\sum_{i=1}^n\|c_iM_iv\|$$
Thus all the elements $c_iM_iv$ are positive multiples of each other. Since the norms of $M_iv$  coincide,  we obtain $M_iv=M_jv$ for any $i,j.$ Hence $M_i=M_j$ for any $i\neq j.$

Comment: That's very clear, thank you!